# i want to change the element image with text in html/stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

am using this code to make hidden dropdown list but instead of that magnifier icon at topright corner, i want to replace it with text "search" or somethinf else, how can i do that? i am a newbie, please excuse me.

link of files https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7cm2DCx8TxvflJKUy1KNU5fbmo1eDJCVU1mQW1FdEtVOE9FbDEzZlM4LVNXSkhVOUlfSUk&usp=sharing

Comment: Paste some useable code please....

Comment: No one is going to click on that link of files.

Comment: Could you post some minimal code that performs what you are talking about and either supply it here in SO or if you think it's a bit too long (which you should try to avoid) then post it on pastebin or a similar site.

Answer (score 0):

Now you'r loading an icon so change this:

```
<li><a href="#" id="searchtoggl"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></a></li>
```

To this:

```
<li><a href="#" id="searchtoggl">Search</a></li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/razitazi/3r18zngb/